# The container 'Web App Libraries' references non existing library 'C:\work\WebRoot\WEB-INF\lib\google-collections-1.0-rc4.jar'

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I have seen similar bugs with "Maven Libraries" but this is for "Web App Libraries".

This is the story: I had the jar in question that I added to the application as an `External Jar` on the location specified. Then I removed it from the Build Path and deleted it from `C:\workWebRoot\WEB-INF\lib\google-collections-1.0-rc4.jar`.

On opening Eclipse I get the error: `The container 'Web App Libraries' references non existing library 'C:\work\WebRoot\WEB-INF\lib\google-collections-1.0-rc4.jar'`

I went to `Project -> Properties -> Build Path` and looked at both jars and `Web App Libraries`... this jar is not in the list of jars.

I tried to right-click and `Refresh` the project.

I tried to `Clean` and `Build` the project again.

None of it worked.

How can I tell Eclipse to stop looking for this jar!?

Comment: Try Closing and then Opening the project.

Comment: I solved the issue by manually deleting the error in eclipse and rebuilding the project. Squelching the error this way seems to have worked. The project builds and runs without errors.

Answer (score 2):

Like is in the comments, I solved this issue closing and opening the project.

The problem was when I shared the project as a git project, then, eclipse change the project from:

```
<eclipse-ws>/<my-project>
```

to:

```
<user>/git/<my-project>
```

But the classpath is still configured to the workspace path, closing and opening the project solve this problem. :)

Thanks to aleksandar for the answer in the comments.